# Cpanel Mail Query

Tags: email, cpanel

I have a client whom's disk space has been taken up by mail.  Is there away that I can delete all old emails that have been deleted/tml files.  I do not want to loose the clients inbox emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the oldest emails/files you can use the following command:

ls -ltr /home/cpanel_user/mail/example.com/user_email/cur

Have a look at /home/cpanel_user/mail/example.com/user_email/

I think you should look on one of this folders:

- new -> unread emails
- cur -> e-mails that have already been read
- .Trash
- .Sent

Also you should use a du -h --max-depth=1 /home/cpanel_user/mail to see what folder use most of disk space.